# I got my laptop keyboard wet

Tags: laptop, hardware-failure, laptop-repair

I don't care about the data and I can easily replace the whole thing.

I want to do surgery and determine what's damaged and if I can fix it, fix it. Money is fine. I'll stop if the processor is unrecoverable.

How do I start testing the hardware downwards?  I'm comfortable replacing parts inside that aren't broken (ram, hd, etc); just upgraded.  I'm very comfortable with programming but hardware has not been a priority.  Google hasn't given me anything really worthy of how far I'm willing to go.

Let's assume the keyboard is kill.  A few spoonfuls of water.  How do I precede?  It's dried, I'm sure, by now. It's been by a heat vent for a week and it's still cold where I live.

Comment: What does "getting wet" mean?  A teaspoon of water might not be all that damaging, on the other hand if a 5 gallon bucket was spilled on it.....  If it's a small amount you may just need to take it apart and reassemble dried out.

Comment: Okay so maybe like a few spoons on a lower end case a week ago.

Comment: There's no way to know but to go inside and just test it as I see it

Comment: A lot of times nothing bad actually happens.  "A week ago" could add to problems if it's just been sitting there since.  Always turn it upside down screen open, to drain, if you don't have time to disassemble on the spot.  It really all depends what got wet and if it was on at the time.  I had one recently I replaced the keyboard with a used that I happened to have, I've had others that just needed to be dried out.  There's really no way to answer this question.  If money is not important, just start and ask more specific questions along the way.

Comment: Have you even dried the unit and remove water out?  Update your question.

Comment: Okay cool.... I'm super intimidated. Let's assume at least the keyboard is kill.  What do I do after that and how do I test/procede after that.

Comment: Let's not assume anything shall we? If the built-in keyboard is toast, then it's toast, use an external keyboard.

Comment: **Most important**: until it's thoroughly dry, unplug and **remove batteries**. Not only the main one (most important), but also the one powering the clock, if accessible. This helps prevent electrolytic corrosion. If batteries are removed immediately, only mechanical components such as fan and disk drive might be damaged, and even then they might be OK.

Comment: I should close this but I'm on a phone. I need to investigate but tonight it's not the night